# How can I add a jqGrid custom error message?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jqgrid

I´m using CodeIgniter and JQuery Grid. I have seen the responses that you have been made here about this topic but I haven't been able to solve my problem with none of them.
The fact is that I have a jqGrid and I need to show the the dialog of insert several types of error that the database server returns.

For example, in one case I have this error:

> Duplicate entry '18-2-1-2012-10-25' for key 'user_store_turn_index'

I need to get this and to show a custom message instead of the current:

> error Status: 'Internal Server Error'. Error code: 500

I've tried with the `aftersubmit` event. I've read the docs and seen the available examples but nothing works.

Inside my JavaScript code I have the function that deals with the after submit event for jqGrid:

```
afterSubmit : function(response, postdata){ 
    test_validate
           return false;
    },
}
```

Then, I write the function that should get the responses for the after submit event:

```
function test_validate(response,postdata) {
    alert('test');
    if(response.responseText == '') {
        success = true;
    } else {
        success = false;
    }
    return [success,response.responseText]
}
```

But nothing happens... Here is the almost complete jquery grid code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

           var grid = jQuery("#newapi_1351189510").jqGrid({
                    ajaxGridOptions : {type:"POST"},
                      jsonReader : {
                      root:"data",
                      repeatitems: false
                   },
                    rowList:[10,20,30],
                    viewrecords: true
                   ,url:'http://localhost/sp/index.php/turn_open/getData'
,editurl:'http://localhost/sp/index.php/turn_open/setData'
,datatype:'json'
,rowNum:'20'
,width:'600'
,height:'300'
,pager: '#pnewapi_1351189510'
,caption:'Apertura de caja'
,colModel:[
{name:'username',index:'username',label:'Usuario' ,align:'center',width:180,editable:false  }
,{name:'TurnName',index:'TurnName',label:'Turno' ,align:'center',width:180,editable:false  }
,{name:'date',index:'date',label:'Fecha' ,width:100,editable:true,edittype:'text',editrules:{required:false,date:true}  ,editoptions: {size: 10, maxlengh: 10,dataInit: function(element) { $(element).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,yearRange: '1982:2022'})}},searchoptions: {size: 10, maxlengh: 10,dataInit: function(element) { $(element).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,yearRange: '1982:2022'})}}}

]       })
            jQuery("#newapi_1351189510")
            .jqGrid('navGrid',
            '#pnewapi_1351189510',
            {view:false,
            edit:'1',
            add:'1',
            del:'1',
            close:true,
            delfunc: null
        },
         afterSubmit : function(response, postdata)
          { test_validate
           return false;
         },
        }, 
        {mtype: 'POST'} /*delete options*/,
        ).navButtonAdd('#pnewapi_1351189510',
                { caption:'', buttonicon:'ui-icon-extlink', onClickButton:dtgOpenExportdata, position: 'last', title:'Export data', cursor: 'pointer'}
                );
        ;

             function test_validate(response,postdata){
             alert('test');
               if(response.responseText == ''){
                 success = true;
                }else{
                success = false;
                }
                return [success,response.responseText]
             }

        });
```

Comment: if you are getting database errors you should be able to trace it back using chrome's development kit or something similar, Can you post your code and explain exactly what you're trying to display in the php response?

Comment: I have no problems with trace database errors. My problem is to show the errors in jquery grid. For example, in this case I´d handle the error and show in the dialog "This operation can not be done in this date".

Comment: its still hard to help without seeing your code.

Comment: afterSubmit : function(response, postdata)
        { test_validate
     return false;
   },
}